# How to update Windows Mobile 6.1 to Windows Mobile 7.5?

Tags: update, windows-mobile

I have HTC TyTN II with Windows Mobile 6.1 and would like to update to Windows Mobile 7.5. I went to Windows Mobile site and downloaded the Zune software but nothing worked. Most of apps these days require Windows Mobile 7.5 and above.

Comment: As a follow up, Windows "Mobile" ceased to exist with 6.5, it is now called "Windows Phone"

Answer (score 27):

What you have is the [Windows Mobile](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Mobile) operating system. The highest stable version Windows Mobile can be upgraded to is 6.5.3. [Windows Phone](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Phone) is ***a new*** mobile operating system which was created to replace Windows Mobile. It cannot be upgraded to from a Windows Mobile device. You will need a new [device](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Windows_Phone_devices) that runs the Windows Phone OS.

Answer (score 13):

It is not physically possible to upgrade your device to WP7.  It doesnt have enough RAM (128MB), Screen resolution (240 x 320), or processor speed(400 MHz) to run the OS.

Even after they've spent a year optimizing the OS, You need at least 256MB, 480x800px, and 800MHz for Windows Phone.

If you want more specs about your device, you can find it here http://www.gsmarena.com/htc_tytn_ii-2024.php

Answer (score 6):

You simply cannot on the TyTN II; if you want to use any version of Windows Phone from 7 and above, you need to buy different hardware.

And the same goes for an upgrade from Windows Phone 7.0, 7.5 or 7.8 to a version 8.x (and above): needs different hardware because of kernel changes.