# upgrade of windows mobile 6.5 to higher

Tags: update

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to update Windows Mobile 6.1 to Windows Mobile 7.5?](https://windowsphone.stackexchange.com/questions/575/how-to-update-windows-mobile-6-1-to-windows-mobile-7-5)

Im using LG Fathom VS 750 windows 6.5 mobile OS. Is there any possible to upgrade to windows mobile 7.5 or higher in this mobile.Can anybody explain how o do this?